# There is a help->search function on the menu bar of mac, how can I use that on windows?

Tags: windows, macos

I have recently bought a windows machine to replace my old macbook. In mac, you can search for items in the menu bar using the search function under help. Just wondering how I can use that on windows. Or is there any applications out there that does that.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a SO question. Please ask it to [superuser.com](http://superuser.com)**

And delete this question from here. Ask on **[superuser.com](http://superuser.com)**

Meanwhile,, this has an answer here already. (Just for reference)

https://superuser.com/questions/258675/is-there-a-tool-or-plugin-that-enables-menu-search-on-windows-like-on-the-mac